# Faceted search with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

In our app, we are building a search for real estate listings.
There are a number of search types:

**1. Based on predefined parameters**

This one is pretty straightforward and achievable with a simple, potentially long, where clause (unless I am not aware of a more fancy/efficient way to do it).

**2. Free text search**

This option is a bit more complex, but also clear. It was done by creating a weighted vector column and the bases for it looks something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE listing ADD COLUMN if not exists weighted_tsv tsvector;

UPDATE listing SET  
    weighted_tsv = l.weighted_tsv
FROM (  
    SELECT id,
           setweight(to_tsvector('english', COALESCE(mls_num,'')), 'A') ||
           setweight(to_tsvector('english', COALESCE(city,'') || ' ' || COALESCE(state_or_province,'')), 'B') ||
           setweight(to_tsvector('english', COALESCE(unparsed_address,'') || ' ' || COALESCE(city,'') || ' ' || COALESCE(state_or_province,'') || ' ' || COALESCE(postal_code,'')), 'C')
           AS weighted_tsv
     FROM listing
) AS l
WHERE l.id = listing.id;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION listing_weighted_tsv_trigger() RETURNS trigger AS $$
    BEGIN
      new.weighted_tsv :=
         setweight(to_tsvector('english', COALESCE(mls_num,'')), 'A') ||
         setweight(to_tsvector('english', COALESCE(city,'') || ' ' || COALESCE(state_or_province,'')), 'B') ||
         setweight(to_tsvector('english', COALESCE(unparsed_address,'') || ' ' || COALESCE(city,'') || ' ' || COALESCE(state_or_province,'') || ' ' || COALESCE(postal_code,'')), 'C');
      return new;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER update_listing_weighted_tsv BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE  
ON listing  
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE listing_weighted_tsv_trigger();


CREATE INDEX if not exists listing_weighted_tsv_idx ON listing USING gin (weighted_tsv);
```

Of course, the document might be changed and adobted as we go.

A search query example might look like this:

```
select l.*, ts_rank_cd(weighted_tsv, query) as rank 
from listing l, to_tsquery('english', 'NB05:* | vancouver') query 
where weighted_tsv @@ query
order by rank desc;
```

**3. Facets**

Here is where we are stuck. The main target is to create an autocomplete for the user when he types in free text in a search. And the idea is to create a categorized list of suggestions ordered by relevance.
For example: If the user starts typing in something that matches mls number, some listing addresses, and some in description, we need to create a categorized list similar to:

```
[
  {
    match: '<mls num>',
    type: 'listing'
  },
  {
    match: '<address>',
    type: 'address'
  },
  {
    match: '<address>',
    type: 'address'
  },
  {
    match: '<description>',
    type: 'description'
  },
]
```

For every element, we'll need to add more details. This example is just to demo the idea.

Now, this could be achieved with a bunch of union statements, one for each category. However, feels like it is not the most efficient way. It will also create maintenance and indexes nightmare.

Is there a way to build facets like search with postgres?
Searching for this, I didn't find anything remotely useful without using elasticsearch or a like.

Comment: "It will also create maintenance and indexes nightmare"  Doing this well is hard.  I think that no matter what, you are looking at **some** kind of nightmare.  Maybe not with indexes but rather with  materialized views, or with heuristics written in the app server.

Comment: How would you do it in elastic search?  Knowing how you would do it there might inspire someone as to how to set it up in PostgreSQL.

Comment: @jjanes elasticsearch has is available as out of the box functionality. Not sure how it's done under the hood.

Comment: Not looking for the "under the hood" info, but the a high level explanation of what the feature actually is. "facets" just redirects me to aggregations, and aggregations don't seem to match what you are describing.